# Is it possible to change activation functions all at once?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, activation-function

I'd like to load a pretrained Inception-V3 model. I have two question.

How can I access to activation functions? Is it possible to change all `Relu` activation functions to `tanh` all at once?

```
import torch
model = torch.hub.load("pytorch/vision", "inception_v3", weights="IMAGENET1K_V1")
```